# Using a variable in SQLAchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to use a variable in SQLAlchemy query but I don't know how to use it.

```
 qry_activity = (db.session.query(Number)
                .filter(Number.network == '%{req_data}%'))
```

where

```
req_data = request.get_data()
```

I am getting value for `req_data`, but when I use it in the query, it is giving `?`

Please help.

Comment: You forgot the `f` before the f-string. `f'%{req_data}%'`. So that's a literal string, the variable isn't substituted.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it but still getting ?

Comment: You should be using `like`, not `==`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `like()` method to do a pattern match. And you have to use an f-string to substitute the variable.

```
qry_activity = db.session.query(Number).filter(Number.network.like(f'%{req_data}%'))
```

Comment: I tried with == and LIKE, but still getting ?

Comment: SELECT "Number".id AS "Number_id", "Number".network AS "Number_network", "Number".activity AS "Number_activity"
FROM "Number"
WHERE "Number".network LIKE ?

Comment: That's a prepared statement, the value is passed in the call to `cursor.execute()`.

Comment: So, is that means that it is working fine and I should get ? in the prepared statement. I tried to replace the variable with an actual string and it was also giving me ? in the prepared statement

Comment: Yes, it's working. The `?` is a placeholder, and it's substituted with the argument to `like` when the statement is executed.